# how to get the count of total rows and sum of a particular column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my original query

```
SELECT acct_id,
       acct_client_short_name,
       acct_cat_code,
       cusip_num,
       symbol_code,
       product_name,
       sec_type_code,
       acct_type_code,
       ann_int_rate_and_maturity_dt_text,
       sd_id,
       loc_code,
       settled_flag,
       td_id,
       eff_dt,
       clearing_code,
       SUM(traded_shrs_num),
       SUM(curr_shrs_num) AS c1
FROM (SELECT 'ID900910' AS acct_id,
             'CNS Netting' AS acct_client_short_name,
             'CNS' AS acct_cat_code,
             cusip_num,
             symbol_code,
             product_name,
             sec_type_code,
             acct_type_code,
             ann_int_rate_and_maturity_dt_text,
             sd_id,
             loc_code,
             settled_flag,
             td_id,
             eff_dt,
             clearing_code,
             traded_shrs_num,
             curr_shrs_num
      FROM [csr_staging].[dbo].[fi_impact_source]
      WHERE (clearing_code = 'MBS'
          OR clearing_code = 'CNS')
        AND (SD_ID >= EFF_DT)) a
GROUP BY acct_id,
         acct_client_short_name,
         acct_cat_code,
         cusip_num,
         symbol_code,
         product_name,
         sec_type_code,
         acct_type_code,
         ann_int_rate_and_maturity_dt_text,
         sd_id,
         loc_code,
         settled_flag,
         td_id,
         eff_dt,
         clearing_code;
```

total rows = 383 rows

how do we get the count of total rows from the above query?

i.e `select count(*),sum(c1) from query1`?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Where are you expecting this value? Within the same query?

Comment: yes i was expecting to do something like select count(1), sum(c1) from the above query. the following query throws an error incorrect syntact ')'  select count(1) from (query mentioned above)

Comment: So just add `count(*) AS total_rows` after `SUM(curr_shrs_num) AS c1`?  Looks like everything is already grouped. After edited comment, you just need to specify the right value to count.

Comment: the above query works fine. But i would like to get the count of the rows from the above query?

Comment: I *think* the OP is after `COUNT({Non-NULLable Column}) OVER () AS TotalRows`? Maybe...? Still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write something like this:

```
SELECT count(*), sum(c1) FROM (SELECT ...) x
```

In other words:

```
SELECT count(*), sum(c1)
FROM (
SELECT acct_id,
       acct_client_short_name,
       acct_cat_code,
       cusip_num,
       symbol_code,
       product_name,
       sec_type_code,
       acct_type_code,
       ann_int_rate_and_maturity_dt_text,
       sd_id,
       loc_code,
       settled_flag,
       td_id,
       eff_dt,
       clearing_code,
       SUM(traded_shrs_num) AS c2,
       SUM(curr_shrs_num) AS c1
FROM (SELECT 'ID900910' AS acct_id,
             'CNS Netting' AS acct_client_short_name,
             'CNS' AS acct_cat_code,
             cusip_num,
             symbol_code,
             product_name,
             sec_type_code,
             acct_type_code,
             ann_int_rate_and_maturity_dt_text,
             sd_id,
             loc_code,
             settled_flag,
             td_id,
             eff_dt,
             clearing_code,
             traded_shrs_num,
             curr_shrs_num
      FROM [csr_staging].[dbo].[fi_impact_source]
      WHERE (clearing_code = 'MBS'
          OR clearing_code = 'CNS')
        AND (SD_ID >= EFF_DT)) a
GROUP BY acct_id,
         acct_client_short_name,
         acct_cat_code,
         cusip_num,
         symbol_code,
         product_name,
         sec_type_code,
         acct_type_code,
         ann_int_rate_and_maturity_dt_text,
         sd_id,
         loc_code,
         settled_flag,
         td_id,
         eff_dt,
         clearing_code
) x
```

This is called using a "derived table".

Comment: it gives me an erorr No column name was specified for column 16 of 'x'.

Comment: SUM(traded_shrs_num) as c2,

Comment: @xrx215 Why are you bothering to calculate the sum of traded_shrs_num when you don't care about it in the outer query? Just as easy to comment out / remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. But this code will give you the total number of records in all the rows as duplicates since the other values are grouped by columns.

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT 'ID900910' AS acct_id,
             'CNS Netting' AS acct_client_short_name,
             'CNS' AS acct_cat_code,
             cusip_num,
             symbol_code,
             product_name,
             sec_type_code,
             acct_type_code,
             ann_int_rate_and_maturity_dt_text,
             sd_id,
             loc_code,
             settled_flag,
             td_id,
             eff_dt,
             clearing_code,
             traded_shrs_num,
             curr_shrs_num
   FROM [csr_staging].[dbo].[fi_impact_source]
   WHERE (clearing_code = 'MBS'OR clearing_code = 'CNS'
         )
         AND (SD_ID >= EFF_DT)
)
SELECT acct_id,
       acct_client_short_name,
       acct_cat_code,
       cusip_num,
       symbol_code,
       product_name,
       sec_type_code,
       acct_type_code,
       ann_int_rate_and_maturity_dt_text,
       sd_id,
       loc_code,
       settled_flag,
       td_id,
       eff_dt,
       clearing_code,
       SUM(traded_shrs_num),
       SUM(curr_shrs_num) AS c1,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE) AS [RecordCount]
FROM CTE
      GROUP BY acct_id,
               acct_client_short_name,
               acct_cat_code,
               cusip_num,
               symbol_code,
               product_name,
               sec_type_code,
               acct_type_code,
               ann_int_rate_and_maturity_dt_text,
               sd_id,
               loc_code,
               settled_flag,
               td_id,
               eff_dt,
               clearing_code
      ;
```

Comment: yes but i would like to get the total rows and also sum (currentshares) from the final query